# Exchange 2003 > 2010 Transition - User failed to log on because their mailbox is being moved

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration

Exchange 2003 to 2010 Transition in a lab environment in VMware ESXi

When I move all of the legacy Exchange 2003 mailboxes to the Exchange 2010 server I see a lot of warnings in the event viewer.

Why is the Event Viewer full of Warning events saying:
"User John Doe ... failed to log on because their mailbox is in the process of being moved"

I'm testing this transition in VMware. I'm the only person accessing these systems and I'm not logging in as these users. Why are there events which seem to indicate all of the users are failing to log in while their mailboxes are being migrated? Is this normal or is this something bad which might be slowing my mailbox moves down?

**Edit:**
Your comments below are accurate in the context of a real production transition but the mystery for me in this situation is this: This isn't a transition in a production environment. There aren't any users other than me logging on. I'm only logging in occasionally with the Administrator account.

This is a test transition on a VMware ESXi lab server completely isolated on a different VLAN on a different switch at a different site away from any real production users, away from any of the users the Event Viewer Warnings are indicating are "failing to log in".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the System Attendant accessing the mailbox as part of the Mailbox Management process or Managed Folder Assistant process?

Answer (score 0):

They should not attempt to access their mail while they're being migrated.  That would be attempting to change things while in a transitional state.  (bad ju-ju)

I recommend scheduling downtime with the users and ensuring that they know not to try to use Outlook or OWA during that time.

Answer (score 0):

You will see **A LOT** of these warnings. Don't worry about them. Users have Outlook open, phones syncing, or OWA open. They're going to be attempting to access the mailboxes somehow. Just give your users a heads up that their Outlook will be offline while their mailboxes are being moved.

Comment: Absolutely. When we upgraded to 2007 we did it in small stages. 100 users at a time. We didn't announce a downtime, just told users that email would be spotty in the evenings but everything would deliver so don't worry.

Comment: This is correct, but he explicitly said it's a lab and he's the only one working on it... so who should be logging on to those mailboxes?!?

Comment: I live in California. All my users where still familiar with the term "rolling blackouts" from our problems a few years ago :-)